# Drive very long WS2812B RGB strip (80 meters)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, led-strip, ws2812b

I have to drive an 80 meters long RGB strip. 100 LEDs/m. What's the best option?

I read Arduino hasn't enough RAM to drive them all so I was thinking about split the strip in slices and every slice be controlled by a Raspberry Pi. And having all the Raspberries internal clocks synced by an Ethernet cable.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is a couple of lines, expecting mountains of effort in return from other people. Please edit your question to show your own work, conclusions and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool in the question editor is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: What about RAM? If you make repeated pattern it does not matter. But drive 8000 chips in one sequence may be problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is unreasonable to drive 8000 leds in one strip due to the massive amount of current involved and the time to update.
eg: around 50mA per led times 8000 is 400A. The strip itself would melt. You'll also need a 2kW 5V supply.
At around 24us per led for the data, you could update it 5 times per second.

Thus you have no choice but to divide and conquer. Plenty of people have driven this number of leds before, so there's plenty of information on the interwebs. There's also plenty of options for hardware to drive this number of leds.

One example is the wled project. With a ESP32 module you can drive 1500 leds in up to 10 strips.
https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/wiki

There's also plenty of hints on wiring and powering.

Answer (score 1):

If it's 80m long you also have to consider transportation, which will also solve your problem.

Pick a convenient length for transportation, for example 2 meters of LED strip with its backing cooling aluminium profile. That's 200 LEDs, for a maximum supply current of 10 Amps. A supply current of 10A maximum means you can use a cheap 5V switching supply, maybe even a brick or wall wart. You could also use a 24V power rail, and 24V to 5V buck converters. That could be cheaper than many 5V supplies, but please don't use the counterfeit LM2596 from ebay.

If the installation will be a panel instead of being linear, you can make panels with any number of LEDs that are manageable with one micro and one power supply, and assemble that into the final installation.

This will make maintenance easier: make several extra panels or 2m bars, so when one breaks down, you can replace it and fix it later. You'll need a way for the panel to know where it is in the whole assembly, you could do that with 2 UARTs. Suppose the TX are on the right and bottom side of each panel. The panel on top has its RX unconnected, so it knows via a pullup or pulldown that it's at Y=0. Then it tells panel one on the bottom "your Y is 1", and so on.

For synchronization, your Ethernet idea seems nice, but it requires a micro with Ethernet.  So if you build a panel, you'll have to make each sub-panel not too small, so you don't use too many Pi's. You could also use one Pi to control 4 panels, or 2 bars, by putting it in the middle.

There is an economic calculation to make on the number of Pi's, and the number and cost of power supplies.

Regarding synchronization, personally I'd send the data to everyone using UDP, and then send one UDP broadcast packet that says "update display now". On a LAN, UDP is pretty reliable, it won't lose packets unless you do something unwise like putting a 100PM switch between two Gb switches.

Answer (score 0):

Build a one-bit uart around the arduino USART combining the clock and data signals to make the 2812 signal waveform allowing the processor to spend most of its time computing the pattern instead of banging bits,